# Redirecting main domain to subdomain, Godaddy Wordpress hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using a subdomain sub.xyz.com(Primary Domain) for my wordpress site on "Godaddy Mananged Wordpress" I have also added main domain lately but keeping the subdomain primary just in case someone try to access xyz.com they don't get an website not found error.

I am not familiar with .htaccess but I found a rule somehwere on stackoverflow for redirection. this is the code I have placed in my .htaccess file, However I want to know if this code is fine by SEO point of view and I wont get any trouble with search Engines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with leaving the connection to WordPress intact. It seems like Google's crawlers are still able to find the pages and the SEO credit doesn't transfer over as well. That's why I remove:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then simply change the .htaccess to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirects all pages on a page to page basis (www.xyz.com/page to sub.xyz.com/page) with or without the www.

I also delete the wp-config.php file just for good measure.

Only the paranoid survive. ;)